# How can I apply the Kruskal-Wallis and Dunn's post-hoc test to a dataframe with many columns with one instruction

Tags: r

I'm quite new with R and I'm stock with this problem. I'm trying to apply the Kruskal-Wallis and Dunn's post-hoc test in a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
##   red    blue    yellow  orange  green
T1  1.01    0.78    0.90    0.57    0.81
T1  4.61    2.39    2.56    2.22    2.82
T1  5.20    5.23    5.10    8.74    7.34
T1  3.63    3.55    3.24    4.28    4.60
T2  1.06    0.46    0.53    0.25    0.33
T2  6.39    8.35    4.36    1.31    2.05
T2  0.48    0.18    0.67    0.13    0.15
T2  1.42    4.43    1.86    3.35    3.72
T3  4.63    2.93    2.41    2.45    2.31
T3  2.10    2.44    2.39    2.35    2.64
T3  3.52    2.06    1.72    1.63    1.38
T3  2.79    1.13    1.30    0.75    0.95
T4  1.05    1.26    0.86    1.10    1.33
T4  1.60    2.05    1.64    0.61    0.34
T4  3.60    3.70    3.37    3.36    2.38
T4  7.05    3.96    3.79    2.08    2.09
```

I have managed to perform the Kruskal-Wallis test using the apply function

```
kruskal<-apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) + kruskal.test(x,df[,1])$p.value)
```

I tried using the same instruction for the posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test from the PMCMR library but it does not work.

So I change the data matrix like this, in order to obtain the test for each column, one by one...

```
##   red    blue    yellow  orange  green   treatment
a   1.01    0.78    0.90    0.57    0.81    T1
b   4.61    2.39    2.56    2.22    2.82    T1
c   5.20    5.23    5.10    8.74    7.34    T1
d   3.63    3.55    3.24    4.28    4.60    T1
e   1.06    0.46    0.53    0.25    0.33    T2
f   6.39    8.35    4.36    1.31    2.05    T2
g   0.48    0.18    0.67    0.13    0.15    T2
h   1.42    4.43    1.86    3.35    3.72    T2
i   4.63    2.93    2.41    2.45    2.31    T3
j   2.10    2.44    2.39    2.35    2.64    T3
k   3.52    2.06    1.72    1.63    1.38    T3
l   2.79    1.13    1.30    0.75    0.95    T3
m   1.05    1.26    0.86    1.10    1.33    T4
n   1.60    2.05    1.64    0.61    0.34    T4
o   3.60    3.70    3.37    3.36    2.38    T4
p   7.05    3.96    3.79    2.08    2.09    T4
```

using the following instruction

```
red<- posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(red ~ treatment, data=df, p.adjust="BH")
```

It works fine, but my dataframe is much bigger than this example, and doing each column one by one is going to take me a lot of time, I'm sure there must be a way I can do all of them with one instruction or maybe a loop.

Comment: `lapply(c("red", "yellow", "blue"), function(y) { posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(x=df[,y], df$treatment, p.adjust="BH") })`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!, the lapply instruction worked great. Thank you again :D